# How to iterate over object/hash in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I have a Javascript object which I have to iterate over the keys of. I need to check whether the key matches with my local variable, if it matches I need the corresponding value of that key.

I'm getting the object using session attribute.
The object looks like this when I see it in alert.
{ 1= Apple , 2= Orange }.

Comment: A *real* map or an object acting like a map?

Comment: use map.get(key), map.has(key), or map.forEach() for all keys

Comment: There are no *map* objects in javascript. What do you think it is? What does your "map" look like?

Comment: I'm getting the map variable using session attribute in script.

Comment: The map object looks like this when I see it in alert. { 1 = Apple , 2 = Orange }

Comment: @ShunmugaAshok That's not a "map", which has a very specific meaning, it's an "object", or some might call it a "hash". Please change the title of your question. Meanwhile, read a basic tutorial on JS objects. You don't need to "iterate" or "check", you just need to access the key, as in `object[key]`. That's what objects exist for.

Comment: @torazaburo  sorry.. I'm new to JavaScript... I'm unable to get the corresponding value when I use object[key]

Comment: If you can't get the corresponding value when you use `object[key]`, then you can iterate all you want and you still won't be able to find the key. Make sure you understand the difference between `object.key`, `object[key]`, and `object['key']`. If the property is not there, then it's not there, and you need to figure out why. What is the result of examining `object[key]`?

Comment: @torazaburo when I use object[key] , it is coming as undefined in alert.

Comment: @RobG I'm getting the object using session attribute.
The object looks like this when I see it in alert.
{ 1= Apple , 2= Orange }.

Comment: @icktoofay I'm getting the object using session attribute.
The object looks like this when I see it in alert.
{ 1= Apple , 2= Orange }.

Comment: @RobG: ES6 added maps, I believe.

Comment: That means the object does not contain that key.

Comment: @icktoofay—ES6 is still in draft, many of the new features aren't widely supported, or are only partially supported, by even the very latest browsers. Support on mobile platforms is particularly poor. It seems to me that ECMAScript is becoming bloated by a hotch–potch of features from other languages that don't add any real value. Is there **really** a need for Array, Object, Map, WeakMap, Set, WeakSet, Symbol. Maybe it's just me…

Comment: @RobG: I agree, but regardless of its merits, ES6 has added maps, so it’s not quite right to say “there are no map objects in JavaScript” any more.

Answer (score -1):

The simplest technique would be to use for...in

```
yourMap = {'one': 1, 'two':2, ......}
keyToLocate = 'one'


for (var key in yourMap) {
   if (key == keyToLocate){
      console.log(key, yourMap[key]);
   }
}
```

Or you can use the [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
for (var key in yourMap) {
   if (yourMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       console.log(key, yourMap[key]);
   }
}
```

Comment: that's not a map, and more to the point, it's silly, you can just ask if(yourMap[keyToLocate]!=null); no looping needed.

Comment: What if I store a key of `hasOwnProperty` in the ‘map’?

Comment: True that would cause an issue. I had a plain old looping lookup technique in my mind.